# Syntax highlighting for .sage in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sage

I started to write some code for sagemath having extension .sage. I write those on sublime text editor. However there is no syntax highlighting
for .sage documents. Sage is mostly based on Python. So is there any way that I can tell sublime to use Python syntax whenever I use .sage file. ?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the main window, click the *View* menu, choose *Syntax*, then at the top *"Open all files with current extension as…"* you can choose which syntax highlighting to use.

Comment: This is what I was looking for ...Thank you very much.